# finding a file starting with a string inside a folder

Tags: php, glob

```
$file = glob("submission/".$iid."/".$yr."/".$sem."/".$sec."/Word/".$sid.".*");
 if ($file!=="")
{ 
    return $path."/". $file;
   break;
}
```

the sid is the student submitted file starting with the student id .I want tyo find the exact file from inside the folder 'word' .The file is like 211000110-Word.docx

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

`glob()` returns an array that you need to further loop through and match the individual values against the value you are looking for.

```
$files = glob("submission/".$iid."/".$yr."/".$sem."/".$sec."/Word/*.docx");

$result = false; 

foreach($files as $file) {
    if($file == "$sid-Word.docx"){
        $result = $file;
        break;
    }
}
```

Turning this into a re-usable function would be a good idea:

```
function get_student_file($sid) {
    $files = glob("submission/".$iid."/".$yr."/".$sem."/".$sec."/Word/*.docx");

    $result = false; 

    foreach($files as $file) {
        if($file == "$sid-Word.docx"){
            $result = $file;
            break;
        }
    }

    unset($files);

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: if the delete the uploaded file.still it displays.Also I want to return the path and file

Comment: If the file is deleted, it won't be available in the array returned from `glob()`. The $result variable should contain the fill path to the file on return from the above function. You can use that to open the file as needed.